# what is the code for Wordpress custom size image url

Tags: regex, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

Can you help me with the right correct code to use for wordpress custom image url to use in the following code instead of exist one https://prnt.sc/h7HnlMy_SagX , and this is the needed size to be used https://prnt.sc/xbNKkJjNFWBv .

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you're using the ACF plugin and then you're getting icon from ACF fields. as it's returning the url then you can manage it from the ACF field setting which size you want to return, I think ACF has that option but I am unsure as I haven't use ACF plugin for many years.

However if you're somehow working with attachment ids and want to fetch the url using attachment id then you can use [wp_get_attachment_image_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) or [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) as per requirement.